# Blog post not properly Edited

Tags: reactjs

I am making a blog website using react and next.js. When I create an edited post and send it to the frontend, the post is no longer edited, there is no font size or any other edit.  Is there a package I can use?

Comment: Youll have to add some snippets or some more information, thsis is too general for us to help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.